# Multiple public IP addresses on CentOS server

Tags: linux, networking, centos, scripting, linux-networking

Is it possible to have multiple public IP addresses (500) on one server running CentOS and switch them without restarting networking service.

I would like to use one public IP per specific service like sending mail, another for receiving mail or calling third party API.

The exact thing that I need is to somehow, when I run specific Python script for service - traffic will use public IP address defined in script.

Comment: The fact that you need to use 500 public addresses on one server is an early indication that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Please make sure you understand meaning of term "public IP address" and either rephrase your question or provide some context.

Answer (score 0):

To add another IP address to your interface is simple:

```
 ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```

Then in your Python code just bind to the IP address you want to use.

Comment: `label eth0:1` can be omitted. And probably should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I will bind range of IPs to server using this [tutorial](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/15/linux-tips-how-to-quickly-bind-a-range-of-ips-on-redhat-based-systems/) then in Python I will to bind it correctly.